# SELECT from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL tables:

tbl_pet_owners:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | pet      | city   | date_adopted |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  2 | jane   | dog      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  3 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-06-11   |
|  4 | jack   | cat      | Boston | 2016-07-11   |
|  5 | jim    | snake    | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  6 | jim    | goldfish | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  7 | joseph | cat      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
|  8 | sam    | cat      | NYC    | 2017-07-11   |
|  9 | drew   | dog      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+-------------+
| pet      | type        |
+----------+-------------+
| cat      | mammal      |
| dog      | mammal      |
| goldfish | fish        |
| goldfish | seacreature |
| snake    | reptile     |
+----------+-------------+
```

Here's the SQL command I want to construct, in English:

Select name, pet, and pet's type where owner's city is Boston. Additionally, no duplicates are allowed in the results set. The result would be:

```
+------+----------+-------------------+
| name | pet      | type              |
+======+==========+===================+
| jane | cat      | mammal            |
+------+----------+-------------------+
| jane | dog      | mammal            |
+------+----------+-------------------+
| jack | cat      | mammal            |
+------+----------+-------------------+
| jim  | snake    | reptile           |
+------+----------+-------------------+
| jim  | goldfish | fish, seacreature |
+------+----------+-------------------+
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT result FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT owners.name, owners.pet, owners.city,
group_concat(DISTINCT types.type separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_owners owners
INNER JOIN tbl_pet_types types ON owners.pet = types.pet
GROUP BY owners.name, owners.pet )
as result WHERE result.city = 'Boston'
```

but I'm getting error: unknown column 'result' in 'field list'

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: You're almost there.. You need to join those two tables using the Pet field as the Join condition. Please do some research on Join types and how they work. Also, This looks suspiciously like Homework, if it is please edit your question and add that bit of detail. We are all here to help, but really don't want to do the initial work for you.

Comment: `SELECT n.name, p.pet, p.type FROM tbl_pet_owners n OUTER JOIN tbl_pet_types p ON n.pet = p.pet` This is to get you started, now you have to figure out how to get distinct values of pets from this

Comment: What is your actual problem? What query have you tried? What was the issue with it?

Comment: As this is obviously homework, I should mention that the first table is not normalized (as I suppose that it is assumed that one owner is always in the same city, in all records) and you (hopefully) wouldn't find it in a real DBMS. I consider it a bad idea to use it for teaching.

Comment: In your query you `select result`, but this is no column. You want to `select result.*`. Then your query should work. But why do you apply `where city = 'Boston'` so late and not right away? Then you wouldn't need the subquery at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally two approaches:

1. Join the tables and then aggregate them somehow in such a way to get distinct pets from the first table and type lists of the second.
2. Get distinct pets from the first table, get type lists from the second, then join.

I find the second approach much better, as you only join what you want to join (distinct pets with type lists). The query is:

```
select
  pet_owners.name, 
  pet_owners.pet, 
  pet_types.types
from 
(
  select distinct name, pet
  from tbl_pet_owners
  where city = 'Boston'
) pet_owners
join
(
  select pet, group_concat(type) as types
  from tbl_pet_types
  group by pet
) pet_types on pet_types.pet = pet_owners.pet;
```

The join-first-muddle-through query looks much simpler and works as well:

```
select 
  po.name,
  po.pet,
  group_concat(distinct pt.type) as types
from tbl_pet_owners po
join tbl_pet_types pt on pt.pet = po.pet
where po.city = 'Boston'
group by po.name, po.pet;
```

Both tables are aggregated (one via `DISTINCT`, one via `GROUP BY`) and this works just fine. There are other cases however, when you need joined aggregates from two tables and this approach fails (typical: multiplied counts). So aggregating before joining is a good habit to stick to.

Answer (score 1):

I've not got a mysql instance handy but I think this is close to what you need:

```
SELECT tpo.name,
       tpo.pet,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tpt.type separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_owners tpo
INNER JOIN tbl_pet_types tpt ON tpt.pet = tpo.pet AND tpo.city = 'Boston'
GROUP BY tpo.name,
         tpo.pet;
```

**EDIT** I've put this together in SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e902e/1/0

Comment: that command returns: a results set with the entry: jane | cat | mammal, mammal. Since jane has two cats, I want the second instance of the cat omitted from the results.

Comment: Working on it. Will post my answer in a minute.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner see above

Comment: @Brinley I've updated the answer and provided a SQL Fiddle link.